# i'm trying to get a value in a dictionary should be a list

Tags: python, dictionary

```
list_of_dict =      
    [{'f_text': 'sample', 'symbol': '*', 'f_id': 246, 'record_id': ['4680', '4679'], 'flag': 'N'}, 
     {'f_text': 'other text', 'symbol': '!#', 'f_id': 247, 'record_id': 4678, 'flag': 'N'}]
```

in the above dictionary some of the `record_id` are in list and some are in string. I'm trying to convert all the values of `record_id` to `list`.

expected output:

```
list_of_dict =     
    [{'f_text': 'sample', 'symbol': '*', 'f_id': 246, 'record_id': ['4680', '4679'], 'flag': 'N'}, 
     {'f_text': 'other text', 'symbol': '!#', 'f_id': 247, 'record_id': ['4678'], 'flag': 'N'}]
```

please guide me with the solution

Comment: Please don't write comprehensions like that. It is bad practice and makes reading your code a nightmare. Comprehensions are for short and simple use-cases. I'd be willing to bet you'd have been able to find the problem yourself if you'd stuck to good code-writing habits.

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach for the same:

```
from copy import copy
list_of_dict=[{'f_text':'sample', 'symbol':'*', 'f_id':246, 'record_id':'4679', 'flag': 'N'},
{'f_text':'sample', 'symbol':'*', 'f_id':246, 'record_id':'4680', 'flag': 'N'},
{'f_text':'other text', 'symbol':'!#', 'f_id':247, 'record_id':'4678', 'flag': 'N'},
{'f_text':'other text', 'symbol':'!#', 'f_id':248, 'record_id':'4678', 'flag': 'N'},
{'f_text':'other text', 'symbol':'!#', 'f_id':247, 'record_id':'4677', 'flag': 'N'},]
visited_fids = {}
cnt = 0
list1 = list_of_dict.copy()
for index, data in enumerate(list1):
    if (data['f_id'] in visited_fids):
        list_of_dict[visited_fids[data['f_id']]]['record_id'].append(data['record_id'])
        list_of_dict.remove(data)
    else:
        data['record_id'] = [data['record_id']]
        visited_fids[data['f_id']] = cnt
        cnt+=1
        
print (list_of_dict)
```

Output:

```
[{'f_text': 'sample', 'symbol': '*', 'f_id': 246, 'record_id': ['4679', '4680'], 'flag': 'N'}, {'f_text': 'other text', 'symbol': '!#', 'f_id': 247, 'record_id': ['4678', '4677'], 'flag': 'N'}, {'f_text': 'other text', 'symbol': '!#', 'f_id': 248, 'record_id': ['4678'], 'flag': 'N'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need dictionary unpacking with two stars, not just one:

```
result = [{**l[0], 'record_id': list(set([x['record_id'] for x in l]))} for _, v in groupby(sorted(list_of_dict, key=lambda x: x['f_id']), key=lambda x: x['f_id']) if len(l:=list(v))]
```

Output:

```
>>> result
[{'f_text': 'sample', 'symbol': '*', 'f_id': 246, 'record_id': ['4680', '4679'], 'flag': 'N'}, 
 {'f_text': 'other text', 'symbol': '!#', 'f_id': 247, 'record_id': ['4678'], 'flag': 'N'}]
>>>
```

Comment: but in your output, for the second dictionary the value of record_id is string..can it also possible to make 'record_id':['4678']

Comment: @sruthi Edited my answer, that's actually simpler!

Comment: i'm getting an error that "NameError: name 'l' is not defined"

Comment: @sruthi Edited my answer

Comment: still I'm getting  "NameError: name 'l' is not defined" 
result = [{**l[0], 'record_id': list(set([x['record_id'] for x in v]))} for _, v in groupby(sorted(list_of_dict, key=lambda x: x['f_id']), key=lambda x: x['f_id'])]
please correct me if i'm doing anything wrong

Comment: @sruthi Edited my answer it works now

Comment: now i'm getting invalid syntax error  File "examples.py", line 14
    result = [{**l[0], 'record_id': list(set([x['record_id'] for x in l]))} if len(l:=list(v)) for _, v in groupby(sorted(list_of_dict, key=lambda x: x['f_id']), key=lambda x: x['f_id'])]
                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @sruthi Sorry typo, edited mine

Comment: still showing invalid syntax

Comment: @sruthi Use it with the original dictionary, it should work, I tested it

Comment: All of this confusion could've been avoided by not trying to cram all of this into a comprehension...